# C# MVC 5 display dynamic binary image as base64

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

OK. I have a basic MVC5 web app. I store images as binary in SQL DB. All good so far.

I can upload different image types: png, jpg, gif ...

My question when I read the image (binary from db) and show it, how can I dynamically format the `data:image/gif;base64,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` ?

More exactly, how can I get the it's type, `image/gif` or `image/png` or `image/jpg` ... from that binary image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [ImageCodecInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imagecodecinfo(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
byte[] bytes; //get from DB
...
using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes)) 
{
    using(var img = Image.FromStream(ms)) 
    {
        var type = GetMimeType(img);
    }
}

public static string GetMimeType(Bitmap image)
{
    var type = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().FirstOrDefault(codec => codec.FormatID == image.RawFormat.Guid);

    return type != null ? type.MimeType : "image/unknown";
}
```